# get_users() when meta_key has multiple serialized values

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I can't seem to find any information online, but what I am trying to do is to get an array of all users based on a value in a serialised `meta_key`, for example:

```
$get_users = get_users(array(
     'meta_key' => 'value_one_of_array'
));
```

Then in the db, the `meta_value` columns would have two stored values such as:

```
meta_key
value_one_of_array , value_two_of_array
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

May be it's help you.

```
$args = array();
if($values_of_array){
    foreach($values_of_array as $key=>$val){
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key'        => '#your_meta_key',
            'value'      => $val
        );
    }
    $get_users = get_users($args);
}
```